Sending transactions to multiple connections?
I'm having issue with state of Solana network / RPC endpoints.
Do you think it's common practices to broadcast transactions to multiple RPC endpoints to increase success rate of transactions ?
Something like this, use Promise.any :
const sendRawTransactions = [connection1.sendRawTransactions(...), connection2.sendRawTransactions(...)]
const success = await Promise.any([sendRawTransactions])

